# Undefined session variable in Get method

Tags: php, session

Hi i'm trying to get the value in session in my get method,actually value is there but its throwing an error that undefined $_SESSION variable as i'm returning value in this get method,so code is not executing furher.Please help[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Bpp.png)

```
<?php

class Session {

    public static function init() {
        session_start();
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        return $_SESSSION[$key];
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        //unset($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
    }

}?>
```

Comment: You mispelled `SESSION`. You have an extra `S`.

Comment: yes sir now i got it... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't spelt SESSION correctly in your get function you have SESSSION .

```
class Session {

public static function init() {
    session_start();
}

public static function set($key, $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

public static function get($key) {
    return $_SESSION[$key];
}

public static function destroy() {
    //unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
}

}
```

Comment: ohh thank  you sir,it was a silly mistake sorry to bother you, n really thanks alot for efforts.

Comment: @geekjv Not a problem. If you are happy this fixed your issue please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a test to see if the key exists before trying to return a non-existent value? Like this perhaps?

```
public static function get($key) {
    return array_key_exists( $key, $_SESSION ) ? $_SESSION[ $key ] : false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i got it it was a silly n stupid spelling mistake.Thanks for your valuable efforts.